# How to get link of xlsx file in GITHUB to be opened as a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I just uploaded a xslx file to my datasets in github. But I cant get the link of raw form so as to fill in
`pd.read_excel("address")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BytesIO`

```
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antony-joy/Data_sets/main/AirQualityUCI.xlsx"
data = rq.get(url).content
df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(data))

Out[4]:
Out[37]:
           Date      Time  CO(GT)  PT08.S1(CO)  NMHC(GT)   C6H6(GT)  PT08.S2(NMHC)  NOx(GT)  PT08.S3(NOx)  NO2(GT)  PT08.S4(NO2)  PT08.S5(O3)       T         RH        AH
0    2004-03-10  18:00:00     2.6      1360.00       150  11.881723        1045.50    166.0       1056.25    113.0       1692.00      1267.50  13.600  48.875001  0.757754
1    2004-03-10  19:00:00     2.0      1292.25       112   9.397165         954.75    103.0       1173.75     92.0       1558.75       972.25  13.300  47.700000  0.725487
2    2004-03-10  20:00:00     2.2      1402.00        88   8.997817         939.25    131.0       1140.00    114.0       1554.50      1074.00  11.900  53.975000  0.750239
3    2004-03-10  21:00:00     2.2      1375.50        80   9.228796         948.25    172.0       1092.00    122.0       1583.75      1203.25  11.000  60.000000  0.786713
4    2004-03-10  22:00:00     1.6      1272.25        51   6.518224         835.50    131.0       1205.00    116.0       1490.00      1110.00  11.150  59.575001  0.788794
...         ...       ...     ...          ...       ...        ...            ...      ...           ...      ...           ...          ...     ...        ...       ...
9352 2005-04-04  10:00:00     3.1      1314.25      -200  13.529605        1101.25    471.7        538.50    189.8       1374.25      1728.50  21.850  29.250000  0.756824
9353 2005-04-04  11:00:00     2.4      1162.50      -200  11.355157        1027.00    353.3        603.75    179.2       1263.50      1269.00  24.325  23.725000  0.711864
9354 2005-04-04  12:00:00     2.4      1142.00      -200  12.374538        1062.50    293.0        603.25    174.7       1240.75      1092.00  26.900  18.350000  0.640649
9355 2005-04-04  13:00:00     2.1      1002.50      -200   9.547187         960.50    234.5        701.50    155.7       1041.00       769.75  28.325  13.550000  0.513866
9356 2005-04-04  14:00:00     2.2      1070.75      -200  11.932060        1047.25    265.2        654.00    167.7       1128.50       816.00  28.500  13.125000  0.502804

[9357 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: I am a bit confused.. should we write read_csv or read_excel and the link you posted is it a raw link? I am not able to get a raw link of my xlsx file. when i press raw link in my github its getting download for excel file but csv it work normally

Comment: My file is CSV, so I'm using ```read_csv```

Comment: I appreaciate it.For csv this is fine i guess. but I am looking for xslx file to be opened as dataframe

Comment: still not working..getting an error ...XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n\n\n\n\n\n<!'
https://github.com/antony-joy/Data_sets/blob/main/AirQualityUCI.xlsx    could you try opening this xlsx file??

Comment: yes, ```url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antony-joy/Data_sets/main/AirQualityUCI.xlsx"```

Comment: @ Johnny...it helps ...Thanks a ton...Could you state from where to get this link...I have been wasting my hours for this? the link which I have been using is url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antony-joy/Data_sets/main/AirQualityUCI.xlsx"    How to get the link for download...

Comment: This url is raw url, or the download  link,  click ```View raw```'s url. Not the URL of the Git page